# Convert String to Color int

Tags: java, android, string, int, remoteview

```
    String ColorString = "Color.BLUE";

    int colorint = Integer.parseInt(ColorString);

    ...

    views.setTextColor(R.id.tvConfigInput, colorint);
```

Why does this crash? in the logcat i get `java.lang.numberformatexception: Invalid int "Color.BLUE"`

I kinda think its at the conversion from string to int it's wrong, because if i just set the int like this:

```
int colorint = Color.BLUE;
```

it works.. but what's wrong with it i don't know.

THANKS very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant value of `Color.Blue` is: -16776961 (0xff0000ff). You are not parsing an int, your are just trying to parse a string and convert it into a int(which won't work).

"Color.BLUE" is not an Integer, but `Color.BLUE` will eventually return a constant value.

You need to do this in order to get it right:

```
int colorInt = Color.BLUE;
views.setTextColor(R.id.tvConfigInput, colorInt);
```

Edit:

```
String ColorString = "BLUE";
int colorInt = Color.parseColor(ColorString);
views.setTextColor(R.id.tvConfigInput, colorInt);
```

Comment: @Jakob : try to use `Color.parseColor`

Comment: thanks, but i'm trying to set the color with the value from the string, I know: int colorint = Color.BLUE; will work.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!! It worked, as i was getting unkown color in the logcat, i tried messing around, and found out you can also you hex color like this. Great Solution, and Thanks @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using enums?

```
public enum Color{
    BLUE(42);

    private int hex;

    Color(int hex){
        this.hex = hex;
    }

    public int getHexCode(){return hex;}
    public String getName(){ return this.name();}
}
```

This way you can assign string literal that could represent multiple values

```
Color.BLUE.getHext() == 42
Color.BLUE.name() == "BLUE"
```